# How to get Checked CheckBox tag value in Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have grouped some checkbox in `GroupBox1, 2, 3` respectively. Now I want to know the tag value ( I am using a `TAG property` to assign a some value to radio button ) of check box which is checked in either of the groupboxes.

Is there any solution besides using `if then` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the group box components and check which ones are check boxes. Afterwards, check their `Checked` state, or whatever you want to do.

C# example:

```
foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (c is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

VB.NET example :

```
For Each c As Control In groupBox1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(c, CheckBox).Checked Then
        ' Whatever
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Well that one is quite obvious. Is there any one line statement to achieve this?